# How to take all of the pages which installed the app - facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Im really new in the bussiness (of facebook applications) and I have a simple question.

How can I take all of the pages which installed my app?

I created an app and some pages registerd to.. so I want to know how to take them + data from them. (like name, ID, link to this page..) I work with PHP and the "new" SDK + I think that I htave to use in FQL but I dont know how..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently [no way to find out from FB who has installed your app](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=29673).

If you have the User IDs stored somewhere in a database, you can get there information by fetching:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID?access_token=XXX
```

...replacing `USERID` with the users ID in your DB, and `XXX` with the token you kept when they approved your app.

Let's hope you kept that info somewhere safe!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be like

```
SELECT id FROM profile WHERE type = 'page' AND id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE is_app_user = 1)
```

that should select all the id's from the accounts on your app that are 1. is a page, 2. is an app user!

Your question is very hard to read / understand so hope this is what your looking for!